# recompress .gz file without unzipping to a temp file first

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

I have test.gz file that I wish to recompress(using better compression ratio):

`gunzip test.gz
  gzip -8 test`

can this be done?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output of the first one into the second one, e.g.

```
gzip -cd test.gz |gzip -9vv > test-recompressed.gz
```

Note that you'll have to recompress to a separate new file I think.

Also higher gzip numbers don't really give much benefit for a lot of compute time, so this may not be worthwhile. If you really need better compression try `xz` which is widely supported nowadays.

Comment: Yes, you certainly need need to recompress to a new file, since if you tried `> test.gz`, then `test.gz` would be immediately deleted and recreated by the `>` before the commands are even run.

Comment: Ah, right - thanks. I wondered if the first gzip might get the inode reference before that happened but you're right, the shell would get there first. In either case you wouldn't save space on disk.

Comment: @Rup: will this work on .tar.gz file also?  I noticed that the resulting .tar.gz file is smaller

Comment: Yes, this will work for any gzipped data, tar or not.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by:

```
tar -cvf files.tar /path/to/file0 /path/to/file1 ; gzip -9 files.tar
```

Or you could use:

```
tar cvf - /path/to/file0 /path/to/file1 | gzip -9 - > files.tar.gz
```